# Why does IIS Express lock files stopping build, rebuild and clean in ASP.Net Core?

Tags: iis-express, asp.net-core-3.1

Every once in a while (and happening to me right now) I'll have a project and something goes wrong and I don't know what.
It will just stop me from building my project.
It just writes this out a million times for each file:

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Warning MSB3026 Could not copy "obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\WebApp.dll" to "bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\WebApp.dll". Beginning retry 1 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\WebApp.dll' because it is being used by another process. The file is locked by: "iisexpress.exe (10396)"  WebApp  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets   4183

IIS is not even in my tray.
How do I kill the process?
And why in the world does it do this in the first place?

Very annoying.  Lose to much time for this stupid thing.

Comment: Open the task manager and kill the iisexpress.exe process (which has the id 10396).

Answer (score -1):

Open the **Task Manager** => find out the **IISExpress** process => **end task**. Now you can compile the code. this does not need Visual Studio restart.